# Finding out the machine name of a field when using Views

Tags: views, entities

When using Views, I always use fields instead of content. But I noticed that Views does not show the machine name of a field and it only *assumes* that you already know it. Is there some other way to find out the machine name?

Knowing the machine name lets me access the field directly like so

```
print $fields['machine_name_here']->content;
```

Comment: Where do you need the machine name? In a template?

Comment: Yes. I need it so I can lay it out like in the sample code above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the settings page of a view, and click on "Theme information"; then you look at the IDs of each field.  For example, if "Theme information" shown this information, then "last_comment_name" would be your machine name.

> Field Node: Last comment author (ID: last_comment_name):

Comment: So it is! Sneaky little bastard hiding in the theme info.

Comment: lol i helped someone yeesssss!!!! 4 years of working with drupal and not knowing a bit of code has finally paid off for me enchance.

Comment: Haha best comment evaaar!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the devel module (highly recommended) you could also insert a function to show you all the available fields for the view:

```
<?php dpm($fields); ?>
```